# how do I make the test wait for useEffect's update to be called first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

```
function App() {
  let [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCtr(1);
  }, []);
              //<-------------------------put a debugger here, only hit once
  return ctr;
}
```

```
// debug this test
it("should render 1", () => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, el);
  expect(el.innerHTML).toBe("1"); // this fails!
});
```

currently this test fails because the test's `expect(...)` finishes before `useEffect` trigger another update. So I want to put something into the test to make it wait for another update finished  so I can see the debugger hit twice. I have tried:

```
it("should render 1", () => {
   const el = document.createElement("div");
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, el);

   for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {   // add a long loop so it could have a chance for the `useEffect` trigged update finishes
      // ...
   }
   expect(el.innerHTML).toBe("1"); // this fails!
});
```

but I still cannot control js runtime that the next job to be executed and looks like `expect(el.innerHTML).toBe("1")` is executed immediately after the loop finishes. So is it a way for me to add something like a trick so I can see the debugger hit twice, i.e let useEffect's update executes before the `expect(...)` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test won't work because you aren't waiting for the re-render to happen -- there isn't anything in your test to trigger the re-render after the `useEffect` calls `setCtr`. TBH, I can't even tell if this code would actually render the DOM to assert tests against...

I reckon a better approach would be to use [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) which gives you the tooling to test your React components without trying to re-invent the wheel.

Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-simple-react-testing-library-demo-fzrv8z?file=/src/App.tsx) with `react-testing-library` setup and a simple assertion that the value `1` is in the DOM. You can run the test in the `Tests` tab in Code Sandbox. Below are the relevant code snippets.

```
// App.tsx
export default function App() {
  const [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCtr(1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
        SO Help: React Testing Library
      </Typography>
      <Typography>{ctr}</Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// __tests__/App.test.tsx
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "../test-utils";
import App from "../App";

test("loads and displays greeting", async () => {
  // Render your APP to the DOM
  render(<App />);

  // Wait for the DOM to update
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText("1")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Update: Solving for OP's original issue

All you need to do is wrap your `render` in `act` from `react-dom/test-utils`.

> To prepare a component for assertions, wrap the code rendering it and performing updates inside an act() call. This makes your test run closer to how React works in the browser.

[Docs for act](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act)

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils"
import App from "./App"

it("should render 1", async () => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  await act(async () => {
    render(<App />, el);
  })
  
  expect(el.innerHTML).toBe("1"); 
});
```

Updated the Code Sandbox as well. Checkout `__tests__/SO.test.tsx`

Comment: my test renders the component,  I have tested that. I just need vanilla javascript code to be able "await" the useEffect's update before executing `expect(...)`, I don't want to use react-testing-library tool even though I do use it in real life, but I want to see how vanilla javascript code can achieve this

Comment: Cool. I'll update the answer to include a solution for this as well. =]

Answer (score 0):

You may need `useLayoutEffect` hook.

```
function App() {
  let [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCtr(1);
    console.log("Executed.")
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("Executed before useEffect called.")
  })

  return ctr;
}
```